# ACTION_CANCEL generated and lose data

Tags: android, touch

I’m working on a 2D game for Android that uses 3 fingers, one/two are on the screen the others are touched and released. Some types of finger usage, some quickly. that is a game where the character walk/run, jump, shot…

My problem is that works fine but sometime is generated the ACTION_CANCEL and I lose the fingers data.

For example, if I press concurrently the 3 fingers I detect on onTouchEvent: ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_POINTER_DOWN (1), ACTION_POINTER_DOWN (2), ACTION_CANCEL.

But also during playing normally, sometime ACTION_CANCEL is generated. Fingers are on the screen but data MotionEvent are all cancelled.. the next touch restart from ACTION_DOWN. So I can't manage the game.

Someone know how to solve my problem? Thanks

I use this (general) code:

```
public class world extends Activity {
    GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        this.glSurfaceView = new worldGL(this);
        setContentView(this.glSurfaceView);
    }

}

class worldGL extends GLSurfaceView {
    world activity;
    world_r renderer;

    public worldGL(Context context){
        super(context);

        this.activity = (world) context;
        this.renderer = new world_r(context);
        setRenderer(this.renderer);

        //...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        //...

        return true;
    }

}

public class world_r implements Renderer {

    public world_r(Context context) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: Found the problem. My smartphone have a 3 finger gesture for screenshot, so this causes the ACTION_CANCEL in the onTouchEvent of GLSurfaceView. Nothing happens anymore because there isn't a onTouchEvent in Activity.
Adding this, I can manage the following events. All the new events go in onTouchEvent in Activity, onTouchEvent of GLSurfaceView never called, so in activity I do this:

if (e.getActionMasked() != MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
     return this.glSurfaceView.onTouchEvent(e);
else {

Comment: There is a way to detect custom gesture set by smartphon brand? That is my xiaomi set by default 3 fingers for screenshot, I want to check if there is something that uses 3 fingers and disable while my app running, by alerting the player.